# Alexa account linking doesn't redirect to LWA auth URL

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit, identity-management, login-with-amazon

I configured an Alexa skill and am trying to enable it for account linking with Login With Amazon (LWA) as an Identity Provider.

Here are the details from the 'Account Linking Screen':

[image]

Here are the LWA security profile configurations:

[image]
[image]

Here's the snippet from my launch request handler in Java:

[image]

Contrary to my expectations the launch request handler doesn't redirect the user to Amazon's login screen.

[image]

It is my understanding that upon launching of the skill, the redirect to the LWA will need to occur (as specified in my Java handler) and the user should be prompted to go to the Authorization URI as specified in the first image.  All the parameters below it in that same image will be automatically appended to the URL as query parameters during that redirection.  Or are they not and I should  manually provide those parameters when populating the `Authorization URI` field on the Alexa Account Linking page?

What am I doing wrong here?  Where can I get some more insight into why the redirection does not occur?

Should the skill pass Alexa certification in order for the Account Linking become functional?

I'm testing the skill from within Alexa Dev console.  I'm using the latest Java Alexa SDK 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users will be automatically redirected to the skills login page (Account Link) when they enable the skill from their Alexa app.

When you send them an `Account Link` card the redirection won't happen automatically, instead the user's has to click on the `Account Link` card from which they will be redirected to the login page.

If you login to your Alexa app or http://alexa.amazon.com  you could see the `Account Link` card there. If you click it, you will be redirected. As of now this is not possible from the Test Simulator.

Comment: Does the skill need to be certified to be enabled from user's Alexa app?

Comment: Nope. You can do it always. "DEV" skills will be available under the "DEV" tab in "Your Skills" section of the Alexa app.

Comment: Does Alexa currently support configuration of multiple security profiles on the skills configuration page.  Say I want to use LWA, Google, Auth0, or my own IdP?

Comment: Nope it allow only one.

Comment: That's a big limitation.  Would it be possible to somehow intercept that flow to allow plugging in multiple providers?  Or do we now need to rely on our own web service to do this kind of work?  Is it something that is planned to be augmented in the future?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own Oauth server which support multiple 'other OAuth'. Never tried it though. But it should be possible.

Comment: How would one then get redirected to that other server?  LinkAccountCard doesn't seem to allow for any URI specification.  Is there other mechanism?

Comment: Clicking on Link card will redirect you to the specified Login Page. If you have control over it, you can redirect it to anywhere.